# iOS 11 beta - Replay Kit - not working properly

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11

In iOS 11 beta, we have an option for screen recording in the control panel. While selecting it, it should show the app lists which has enabled with Broadcast extensions(ReplayKit).

But, in iOS 11 beta, it does not show any apps.

I have already installed the "MobCrush" app in my device. In WWDC 2017, Apple showed the ReplayKit demo with this app only.

I don't know if any fix in the next version updates. Please share anything you know guys.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for App Developers (MobCrush in your example) to add support for ReplayKit2.

Specifically they need to write the "Upload Extension" which will do the job of uploading your screen-recording/broadcast to the MobCrush servers and from where it can be broadcasted.